# Mirth: Evaulating SWITCH versus IF Statement

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I'm using a product called Mirth (version 3.6) to execute transform code.  It doesn't seem to have an interactive debugger so can anyone explain why the following code in a destination transform will only log from the IF statement and not from the SWITCH statement?  Works perfectly from regular java running in Eclipse but this code is executing inside a JavaScript engine that Mirth uses (Rhino if I'm not mistaken).

```
for each (node in msg['PID'].children()) 
{
    if(node.name() == "PID.3")
        {
        logger.info("IF Succeeded");
    }

    switch(node.name())
    {
        case "PID.3": 
             logger.info("SWITCH Succeeded"); // This line never logs
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue with Mirth Connect since it uses Rhino as it's engine (uses java as well as javascript).
The Switch statement doesn't work with a Java String object
The simple solution is to convert any unknown string type to a native JS string by concatenating an empty string to the questionable string (i.e. str + '')

```
// See in action
for each (node in msg['PID'].children()) 
{
    var nodeName = node.name();
    if (nodeName != "PID.3")
    {
       continue;
    }
    var type = typeof(nodeName);

    logger.debug('NodeName: ' + nodeName + '; Type: ' + type);
    if (type == 'object') {
        logger.debug('Type is object');
        if (nodeName instanceof String) {
            logger.debug('Object is Java String instance');
        } else {
            logger.debug('Object is not Java String instance');
        }
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        logger.debug('Type is JS string.');
    } else {
        logger.debug('Type is not object or string. Type: ' + type);
    }

    // Works with String object or JS string
    if (nodeName == "PID.3")
    {
       logger.info("IF Succeeded");
    }

    // Only works with JS string
    switch (nodeName)
    {
        case "PID.3": 
            logger.info("SWITCH Succeeded"); // This line never logs
            break;
        default:
            logger.info("SWITCH not matched: " + nodeName);
            break;
    }

    logger.debug('Convert to JS string');
    nodeName = nodeName + '';
    type = typeof(nodeName);
    logger.debug('Converted Type: ' + type);
    if (type == 'object') {
        logger.debug('Converted Type is object');
        if (nodeName instanceof String) {
            logger.debug('Converted Object is String instance');
        } else if (nodeName instanceof string) {
            logger.debug('Converted Object is string instance');
        } else {
            logger.debug('Converted Object is not Java String instance');
        }
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        logger.debug('Converted Type is JS string.');
    } else {
        logger.debug('Converted Type is not object or string. Type: ' + type);
    }

    switch(nodeName)
    {
        case "PID.3": 
            logger.info("SWITCH with js string Succeeded");
            break;
        default:
            logger.info("SWITCH with js string not matched: " + nodeName);
            break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @a_Tom was kind enough to answer this one. http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?p=263980#post263980